# Can a DMM measuring voltage inject voltage?

Tags: voltage, multimeter

Here are two behaviors that I cannot explain:

1. I have an ESP8266-12F chip that is connected to an USB-TTL adapter (FTDI) through a breadboard.

The adapter has TX and RX pins connected to RX and TX of the ESP chip directly.
The adapter has GND and 3V pins connected to the breadboard so I have 2 rails available to pull up/down some pins of the ESP chip on top of VCC/GND.

Here is first issue: when I plug the black probe of my DMM somewhere in the ground rail, very often the LCD screen of my desktop PC goes black (like off, then on) for a second. Why so? (please remember the FTDI is powered via USB from that PC).

2. When I then put the red probe of my DMM to GPIO2 of the ESP chip, it lights on the built-in led of the ESP chip.

Why so? I always thought a voltmeter is "passive", like it does not disturb the circuit I am testing.

I tried with an other DMM: this one does not trigger issue number 1 (screen never flickers), but does light the blue LED as soon as I put the red prob on the pin (eventhough less bright).

Both DMMs are on "V" (DC) position when measuring (not in diode mode or else), auto range.

Edit : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tptn1OpsAoM

Comment: Could you please post a photo of your setup? It seems a grounding problem to me, but it's difficult to diagnose with only a verbal description of the thing.

Comment: Is the first DMM powered from an AC outlet, or does it have any connections to other equipment?

Comment: Musa, in your first case (problem with one DMM but not the other one) it is likely something related to what @Peter hints towards. The second case that applies to both DMMs makes me wonder if you have your DMM set to measure Ohms (resistance.) If so, it does provide a small voltage for that purpose (which may auto-adjust) and this may, via protection diodes present on I/O pins, supply power enough that you can see an LED.

Comment: Other modes can inject voltage. That's how the diode or the resistance or continuity features work. The voltage function shouldn't.

Comment: Please draw a schematic of everything connected, make and model of the multimeter and what setting.

Comment: The DMM is on the "V" range but is the red probe in the "A" socket?

Comment: drawing a schematic + filming a short clip in a brief moment.

Comment: @LorenzoDonati--Codidact.com https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tptn1OpsAoM

Comment: Where is the red probe when you are touching the black probe to ground? Could it be accidentally touching something conductive?

Comment: I'm wondering if GPIO2 is set to be digital input, and is floating? A floating voltmeter probe (or a finger for that matter) can drag it low via its 10Meg resistance. More likely, it can inject 50/60 Hz picked up by your electric field environment. Especially when you say that multimeter 2 lights up the blue LED less strongly.

Comment: @glen_geek very interesting. When I put my black probe on ground and red probe on gpio2, then resets the chip, my DMM reads 3v. When I remove the red prob 1 second and put it back on gpio2, DMM now reads 0.8v and led lights up. Is such a thing normal with DMMs? You cannot trust it? If there was no LED, I would have always thought that pin was low, while it was always high but "pulled down" by my probes ? Worrying... Also I can confirm touching the pin with the finger lights up the LED as well.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy red probe is floating, it touches nothing. I found a way to reproduce this "bug" 99% of the time : if i shake both my probes and their cables in the air for 2-3 seconds then stab the black probe in the gnd rail of my breadboard, it always flickers my pc screen on/off !

Comment: GPIO pin that is *input* (rather than output) has **very** high equivalent input resistance - higher than your voltmeter's 10Meg input resistance. So a voltmeter probe can easily drag a floating input pin down to ground. For CMOS logic, a hand waving above the chip can change logic states of floating inputs...the hand is likely attached to a charged body.

Comment: @glen_geek ok, that makes sense. I consider mystery #2 solved. Thank you.

Comment: Still investigating mystery #1. I noticed my probes maybe act as caps when I shake them? https://i.imgur.com/5UdGCHG.jpg Same reader detects 10Meg resistor instead of 3k pF cap when I let the probes/cables at rest a bit. Maybe it injects volts when I pick my black probe and plug into gnd rail? I swapped the probes with differents DMMs and I can at this moment quite confidently confirm the problem are the probes.

Comment: Shaking the probe/cable, disconnected from the DMM, and touching the ground rail also triggers this black magic. This only happens with the silicon and gold plated probes. I tested with "lower end" probes : they do not trigger this inconvenience. I will try to measure how much volts this sorcery injects after I have explained my wife why I'm playing helicopter with my probes.

Comment: I am thinking that shaking the probe in the air may charge the probe via tribo-electric effect.

Comment: @Musa I just had a chance to check out the video. Very nice. Well-done! I don't have an idea, just yet. But I just wanted to thank you for a well-prepared question, with video. Far better than expected! +1 on the question for that.

Answer (score 4):

> Can a DMM inject voltage?

If your DMM is set to measure Ohm's, continuity, or "diode", then a small amount of current will be injected into the circuit under test. And, depending upon the impedance being measured (and the DMM) several volts may develop across the DMM leads.

For example, I am able to make a string of blue LEDs light up (dimly, but distinguishably on, in a dark room) simply by testing them for continuity with my DMM.

A DMM set to read current (i.e. mA etc.), on the other hand, can act essentially like a short circuit. Probing between a GPIO pin and ground or Vcc/Vdd with the DMM on a current scale can definitely change the state of the pin.

Comment: This is what I know of as well. Voltage amount injected in diode mode depends on DMM as well (some +2V, some even +3V, etc). You answered the title but that does not answer my problem, sorry I did not know how to title my post.